# Markov property in proof

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I'm trying to prove that:

$\mathbb{P}(X_{n+m}=x_{n+m}|X_{n}=x_{n},...,X_{0}=x_{0})=\mathbb{P}(X_{n+m}=x_{n+m}|X_{n}=x_{n})$ for $m \geq 1$ and for all $x_{n+m},x_{n},...,x_{0} \in E$, where E is the state space, by induction.

In my proof after the inductive assumption step, I have stated that I've used the Markov property below but I'm not 100% sure if that's valid. Is the below okay?

$$P(X_{n+k+1}=x_{n+k+1}|X_{n+k}=x_{n+k},X_{n}=x_{n},...,X_{0}=x_{0}) = P(X_{n+k+1}=x_{n+k+1}|X_{n+k}=x_{n+k},X_{n}=x_{n})$$

Comment: Sure, since, by the (simple) Markov property, both are equal to $$P(X_{n+k+1}=x_{n+k+1}\mid X_{n+k}=x_{n+k})$$